# Node Js Class Syntax

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Not being able to understand the retrieve the value from a Node JS Class

[Here the [Symbol.iterator '']]alert(`Hello, ${this.name}!`);
 Is there any other way round??

```
class User {
  name = "Anonymous";

  sayHi() {
         [Here the [Symbol.iterator '']]alert(`Hello, ${this.name}!`);
  }
}

new User().sayHi();
```

Im expected to get Hello, John, but i get Hello, '${this.name}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
class User {
  name = "Anonymous";

  sayHi() {
        alert(`Hello, ${this.name}!`);
  }
}

new User().sayHi();
```

The above code runs correctly and it should alert `Hello, Anonymous!` rather than `Hello, John!`

Comment: What is it with (espace character)?? Do we need to use it and how abt using espace character into a string !!

Comment: you can use \`INSERT INTO tbl_products(name, price) VALUES ("${this.name}",${this.price})\`;

Answer (score 0):

so this is a constructor class, which means all of the declarations will point to the instance of the class, in addition, i you want to the class to have its own properties  use the static keyword

```
class Person {
  static user = "tony";
  static getUser() {
    return this.user;
  }
}

console.log(Person.getUser());
```